# PHPMailer error while checking SMTP

Tags: php, email, gmail, wamp, phpmailer

I would like to create a website that requires registration, for a school project. I am using Windows 10, with Wamp Server 3.1.0. I would like, upon registration, for an email to be sent to the user's email address. Just to test it. I installed PHPMailer, using the composer. I run the example "check_smtp.php" that's in the PHPMailer github. When I run the example as it is, just using "smtp.gmail.com" instead of "smtp.example.com", what I get is this:

```
2017-12-15 17:02:11 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=30, options=array() 
2017-12-15 17:02:11 Connection: opened 
2017-12-15 17:02:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e124sm2870640wmg.34 - gsmtp 
2017-12-15 17:02:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO Angel 
2017-12-15 17:02:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [46.176.22.104] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
2017-12-15 17:02:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2017-12-15 17:02:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
2017-12-15 17:02:12 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [C:\wamp64\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 404] SMTP error: Failed to start encryption: Connection failed. 
2017-12-15 17:02:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

I checked the php extensions, just to make sure, and php_openssl is activated.

I have been fighting with this the whole day, checked every solution i could find, but I cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: Try to find problem source step by step. Likely you need to add option in settings to prevent checking ssl. Or you need to fix mail scripts.
Google this:
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1 -->
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086 -->
SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed -->[C:\wamp64\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 404] -->
 SMTP error: Failed to start encryption: Connection failed.

Comment: Read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) - it describes exactly this problem and how to fix it. You have a TLS problem, probably that you need to update your CA certificates. This has been asked and answered may times on here. The first place you should look for info on any open-source project is official documentation - don't rely on others to look things up for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to GMail SMTP (PHPMailer) - Certificate Verify Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650796/cannot-connect-to-gmail-smtp-phpmailer-certificate-verify-failed)

Comment: Also when writing a question, make the title meaningful & specific –  `PHPMailer error while checking SMTP` is far too vague – it could be one of hundreds of things; use the message you see, so perhaps `PHPMailer error 'SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed' when connecting to Gmail`. Stack Overflow has plenty of help for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Synchro Thank you very much for taking time to reply to my answer. If I had not tried the solutions on the troubleshooting guide many times over, and the cacert fix you propose, I would not have asked a separate question.  I will try to make my titles mre specific from now on.

Comment: So you’ll have no problem posting the results of the tests you did, particularly the openssl tests.

Comment: _I checked the php extensions, just to make sure, and php_openssl is activated._ How did you check this?