# Uncaught exception 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' could not connect SMTP certificate error

Tags: ssl, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send email from my localhost with gmail smtp server and phpmailer.
 when I submit my form I am getting following error.

```
2018-02-05 18:36:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e22sm5767718ioj.79 - gsmtp
2018-02-05 18:36:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2018-02-05 18:36:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [142.237.177.21]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2018-02-05 18:36:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-02-05 18:36:19 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2018-02-05 18:36:19 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [C:\wamp64\www\test\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 405]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-02-05 18:36:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-02-05 18:36:19 
2018-02-05 18:36:19 
2018-02-05 18:36:19 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' with message 'SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.' in C:\wamp64\www\test\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 1898
```

I tried everything I could do but nothing works out.

below is my code .

```html
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{ 

 private $conn;
 
 public function __construct()
 {
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->dbConnection();
  $this->conn = $db;
    }
 
 public function runQuery($sql)
 {
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
  return $stmt;
 }
 
 public function lasdID()
 {
  $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
  return $stmt;
 }
 
 public function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code)
 {
  try
  {       
   $password = md5($upass);
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass,tokenCode) 
                                                VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code)");
   $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
   $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
   $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
   $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
   $stmt->execute(); 
   return $stmt;
  }
  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
 }
 
 public function login($email,$upass)
 {
  try
  {
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
   $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
   $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   
   if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
   {
    if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
    {
     if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
     {
      $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
      return true;
     }
     else
     {
      header("Location: index.php?error");
      exit;
     }
    }
    else
    {
     header("Location: index.php?inactive");
     exit;
    } 
   }
   else
   {
    header("Location: index.php?error");
    exit;
   }  
  }
  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
 }
 
 
 public function is_logged_in()
 {
  if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
 
 public function redirect($url)
 {
  header("Location: $url");
 }
 
 public function logout()
 {
  session_destroy();
  $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
 }
 
 function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
 {      
   

 require 'C:\wamp64\www\test\phpmailer\src\Exception.php';
 require 'C:\wamp64\www\test\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php';
 require 'C:\wamp64\www\test\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                 
  $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';      
  $mail->Port       = 587;
  $mail->Username= "solankij978@gmail.com";  
  $mail->Password= "9724929143";            
  $mail->SetFrom('solankij978@gmail.com','Sachin Patel');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('deeshanpatel@gmail.com','Sachin Patel');             
  $mail->AddAddress($email);
  $mail->Subject    = $subject;
  $mail->MsgHTML($message);
  $mail->Send();
 } 
}
```

please help me out.

Comment: Can you please limit the code to the absolutely necessary parts? The session handling for example is superfluous in this extract.

Comment: Please also remove the credentials; they are valid credentials for a google account.

Comment: Also **read the error message** - the significant part is "certificate verify failed", and the underlying reasons and solutions for that are described in detail in the troubleshooting guide the error links to, and also many questions on here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to GMail SMTP (PHPMailer) - Certificate Verify Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650796/cannot-connect-to-gmail-smtp-phpmailer-certificate-verify-failed)

Comment: I tried that earlier @Synchro and I also tried to update my certificates in my php.ini file but I am getting same errors

Comment: OK, so check the certs with openssl, as described in the guide. Does PHP show it's using your custom CA certs if you run `php -i` or `phpinfo()`?