# problem with PHPMAILER Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, phpmailer

I Have Problem With PHPMAILER it's Work Good in localhost but in server give me error

PHPMAILER Code

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

function sendMail($driver, $driverUser){

    // Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'wastaapplication@gmail.com';                // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = '*******';                      // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('wastaapplication@gmail.com', 'Wasta Driver');
        $mail->addAddress($driver, $driverUser);     // Add a recipient

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'New Order';
        $mail->Body    = ' مرحبا ' . '<strong>' . $driverUser . '</strong>' . '  لديك طلبيه جديده برجاء مراجعه برنامج الطيارين ';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }

}
```

Error

```
2019-04-30 05:14:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-server.issgroups.org ESMTP Exim 4.91 #1 Tue, 30 Apr 2019 07:14:51 +0200 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2019-04-30 05:14:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO wastetkheer.com
2019-04-30 05:14:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.issgroups.org Hello wastetkheer.com [138.201.107.252]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2019-04-30 05:14:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2019-04-30 05:14:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2019-04-30 05:14:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-04-30 05:14:51 
2019-04-30 05:14:51 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

i'm trying change SMTPDebug To 1
& //$mail->isSMTP();

it's work good in local host not in server
I guess the problem is with the SMTP authentication, but I couldn´t find the problem.

Comment: What server are you using? Some hosting companies blocks SMTP-ports and forces you to use their SMTP-relay (like GoDaddy). Also, if you get "Could not connect to SMTP host", it's most likely not the authentication (since that requires an established connection to the host).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to GMail SMTP (PHPMailer) - Certificate Verify Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650796/cannot-connect-to-gmail-smtp-phpmailer-certificate-verify-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Please search before posting as this has been answered many times before.

It's failing immediately after STARTTLS, indicating a TLS error. This is very common with gmail because their CA root certificates changed about a year ago to ones that are not present in many older OSs. It's working for you on localhost because your local OS does not have outdated CA certificates.

Read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure) which tells you exactly how to deal with this.

It could also be down to your ISP redirecting SMTP traffic to their own mail server, causing a certificate name mismatch - the guide provides ways of diagnosing the exact problem.